# An explicit $\Lambda_R^\ell(M)$ when $M$ is not free

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, ring-theory, modules, differential-forms

Let $\Lambda_R^n(M)$ be the nth exterior power of an $R$-module $M$. Let us assume $M$ is finitely generated.

When $M$ if free, say, $M=R^{\oplus d}$, we know \begin{equation}
\Lambda_R^n(M)\cong R^{\oplus {d\choose n}},
\end{equation}  and there is a very canonical isomorphism which maps \begin{equation}
(\Sigma r_{j1}e_j)\wedge(\Sigma r_{j2}e_j)\wedge\cdots\wedge(\Sigma r_{jn}e_j)
\end{equation} to the determinants of ${d\choose n}$ minors of the matrix $(r_{ji})$.

For general modules things might not be so neat. I still wonder, however, whether we have something similar that can help me understand exterior powers more concretely and make computations more direct.

Thanks very much!